# Opportunity Stage value is 'CLose Lost' ........ pls help me

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community

My requirement is If Opportunity Stage value is 'CLose Lost' then a visual page will call and dynamically display the competitor, who gain the opportunity.

I am trying with below code, but it is not working .

?Can you please help me.

### OppTestPAge

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" >
<script src="/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js"></script>
<script>
var arrId = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}';
var queryresult = sforce.connection.query("Select StageName from Opportunity where id='"+arrId+"'");
var records = queryresult.getArray("records");
if(records[0].StageName=='Closed Lost')
{
window.open('/apex/searchOpp?id='+arrId ,'lookup','width=800,height=480,scrollbars=yes,left=200,top=100');
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

### searchOpp

## Hello Opportunity

Comment: What error are you getting? I just tested with your code and it seems to work perfectly fine, I just ran it from my JS console and it works okay, try adding in a few console.log() and display the text to the JS console. If you paste that and or a screenshot I should be able to help more.

Answer (score -1):

I placed inline visual force page at wrong location.